# Get rid of the margin on Image Asset for launcher icons on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying hard to get rid of the extra margin around the ic launcher icons generated by Android Studio without luck. I know this is one of Google's material design trends. Though, the icons are so small on devices which is ugly.

I have Googled for around three hours and the only workaround I could find is to generate the clipart with a transparent background and photoshop the background with rounded corners which is pretty slow.

Is there a better solution than this?

Thank you.

Comment: I think this link may help you https://reiszecke.github.io/AndroidAssetStudioFullsize/icons-launcher.html#foreground.space.trim=1&foreground.space.pad=0&foreColor=607d8b%2C0&crop=0&backgroundShape=none&backColor=ffffff%2C100&effects=none

Comment: @Sana, this is the tool that allows you to create the transparent background solution and it does not help. Thanks, anyway. I appreciate it.

Comment: Welcome Limmen.I am sorry that this is not of helpful link.Actually I first tried with a icon and there were chances to get rid of margin that comes in android studio.Anyways I hope you find a way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the [Designing adaptive icons blog post](https://medium.com/google-design/designing-adaptive-icons-515af294c783), the adaptive icon images created in the `drawable` directory for use on API 26+ devices follow the adaptive icon size and shape:

[image: adaptive icon size]

You'll note that while the entire image **must** be 108dp by 108dp, the actual visual area is only the center 72dp - the outer edge is only seen when dragging the icons around (where parallax effects may cause it be visible).

The Pixel Launcher, as well as many third party launchers, enforce the use of adaptive icons on API 26+ devices, so you should always design with that requirement in mind - the alternative, in the Pixel Launcher's case for instance, is to place your non-adaptive icon within a white circle.

Therefore you should always design your icon such that the background layer takes up the full size, but any foreground image you put on top of that background layer should be contained within that center area.

You can't just remove that margin without the foreground image being messed up, but as per the [Implementing Adaptive Icons follow up blog post](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/implementing-adaptive-icons-1e4d1795470e#1294), you **can** remove any white excess around the foreground by putting your trimmed image within a transparent drawable of 108dp x 108dp by using an `InsetDrawable`.

```
<!-- Center a 54x54dp image in the 108x108dp size of adaptive icons -->
<inset
  android:drawable="@mipmap/ic_fg_trimmed"
  android:insetLeft="25%"
  android:insetTop="25%"
  android:insetRight="25%"
  android:insetBottom="25%" />
```

Although this would have to be something you'd need to do to the `ic_launcher_foreground` image yourself after the fact.

A better solution, in most cases, is to use vector drawable images as the input to the Android Studio Image Asset wizard - this will ensure they are always the right size and don't take up any additional space in your APK.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I just wanted to learn about the adaptive icons before replying. I am not sure I understand it fully. Though, I have decided to follow your advice. I decided to generate the icons normally then handle the legacy ones separately with None instead of Square which enlarged the icons. Testing the adaptive icons on 26+ emulators, they looked good. Thanks for the detailed information.

Answer (score -1):

I think i had the same problem as you. I solved this with a nasty hack, in the AndroidManifest.xml I just changed the roundIcon to point to the standard icon.

```
<application
…
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
```

See more from [the docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive#creating_adaptive_icons_in_xml).